# Trying to create a new line after a collapsed YAML fold results in a new line inside the folding region instead

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recorded a video, hard to explain what I exactly encounter. The video best describes my issue - I have a folded section, and I want to keep editing and adding code after the folded section. Pressing enter at the end of the folded section expands it and adds a blank line right after where the section is folded.
Another example - in the video, If I want to add another `orgId` between the 2 that already existed, pressing enter after the first one just expands the folded section and does a lot of mess. What is the point of folded sections if I can't edit code when it's folded?
link: https://streamable.com/yhlt2u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue and is not limited to just YAML, but also happens with things like region folding comments. Take a look at this issue ticket: [[folding] pressing Enter in collapsed region should add new line outside region #91600](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/91600), where [a maintainer (Martin Aeschlimann) commented](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/91600#issuecomment-591891879):

> The position at the end of the line is considered inside the folded range. The cursor is before the `...` and that's where all typing applies to.

I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up, and subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress on fixing it. It's currently sitting in the backlog.